# how to fetch data in firebase when the child is nested from a table

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

The above image is my database structure in firebase. I don't know how to fetch the data inside the child `Latlng`. How would I fetch it?

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/retrieve-data

Comment: Why would you rate me down! If you know this question, then just answer me. Not by voting down!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your project, your need to have a POJO representing the "Driver" entity. Something like:

```
public class Driver {

    private String age;
    private String busNum;
    // etc ...

    private HashMap<String, Object> Latlng;

    public Driver() {
    }

    // getters ...

    public HashMap<String, Object> getLatlng() {
        return Latlng;
    }

}
```

In `Firebase`, inner objects have to be declared has `HashMaps<String, Object>`, where the `String` is the key and the `Object` can be any other object in your model (in your case a `Float` I'd bet).

Now, if you want to read some value **only once**, simply call `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` method, like this:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                .getReferenceFromUrl(URL_DRIVERS)
                .child(driverKey)
                .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        Driver driver = dataSnapshot.getValue(Driver.class);

                        // And here you can access Latlng object
                        latitude = driver.getLatlng().get("latitude");
                        longitude = driver.getLatlng().get("longitude");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                        // handle error ...
                    }
                });
```

Note: URL_DRIVERS would be your root node url (https://your-project.firebaseio.com/) plus your Driver node location (in your case "Driver")

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to know how to get those values one time, then its something like this:

```
String lat;
String lon;

String userId = // [get userID from firebase]

String mDatabase = // [get database ref from firebase]


mDatabase.child("Driver").child(userId).child("Latlng").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(
    new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            lat = dataSnapshot.child("latitude").getValue();
            lon = dataSnapshot.child("longitude").getValue();

            // ...
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.w(TAG, "getUser:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
            // ...
        }
    });
```

Comment: If you're wanting to track movements in realtime, that is different but the answer is still provided in the link I gave before.

Comment: Did you mean "latitude" and "longitude" (String) instead of plain latitude and longitude?

Comment: @josemigallas it's the plain latitude and longitude

Comment: I dont know i was just trying to get the basic idea across

Comment: Then I am telling you. However you only wanna give the basic idea, your code is strictly wrong and whoever use it won't ve able to compile.

Answer (score 0):

What I can understand from the screen shot of data you shared that you are pushing values in **Driver** node, so if I am guessing right, it is not the user id that you can get and pass in code(as mentioned in other answers).

In that scenario you have to get snapshot of **Driver** node

1.) Create a POJO of Drier entity, Driver.class

```
public class Driver {

private String age;
private String busNum;
// etc ...

private HashMap<String, Object> Latlng;

public Driver() {
}

// add all getters and setters...

public HashMap<String, Object> getLatlng() {
    return Latlng;
}}
```

In your activity class

```
DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Driver");
    mDatabaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            System.out.println("There are total" + dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount() + " values");
            for (DataSnapshot driverSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                SampleContent content= driverSnapshot.getValue(Driver.class);

                System.out.println(content.getLatlng().toString());

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Note: I have not run the code there may be syntax errors, pardon me for that.

Also go through https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/retrieve-data for more details.