# Firebase Database reference in android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

My current code is this:

```
String key = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("posts").child("???").child("numLikes").toString;
```

How to get numLikes value?

Comment: refer this https://stackoverflow.com/a/39510554/1848157

Comment: add firebase tag, reword the question and fix image display

Answer (score 2):

```
final ArrayList<Integer> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        DatabaseReference dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("posts");
        dbRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                arrayList.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    int numLike = ds.child("numLikes").getValue(Integer.class);
                    arrayList.add(numLike);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

Try this code, here you don't know pushkey so I have used forEach loop to jump one level down. The arraylist used here will contain all numLikes for your users.